# Запуск linux на машине с GTX 1060

Tags: linux, железо

Недавно поменял видеокарту на GTX 1060, пришлось перепрошить биос, чтобы мать видела карточку. До этого стояла GTX 660, ubuntu работала, все было ок. Сейчас пытаюсь запустить с флешки ubuntu 16.04, при запуске он пишет что-то про unknown chipset(не успеваю записать, ошибка буквально долю секунды мелькает), затем пытается запустить систему и после этого монитор гаснет, аргументируя это тем, что "ВХОД НЕ ПОДДЕРЖИВАЕТСЯ". Пытался воткнуть монитор в встроенный GPU - та же история. Пробовал другие дистрибутивы с GUI(Arch, xubuntu) - все то же самое. Есть идеи что не так? Буду рад любому дельному совету.

UPD: Запустил на одной встроенной графике - все работает. То есть проблема, скорее всего, именно в GPU.

Comment: `не успеваю записать` попробуйте сфотографировать. И запуститься, оставив только встроенную видяху.

Comment: @alexolut Сфоткать попробую, да. Запуститься на встроенной тоже щас попробую, но вообще суть этих манипуляций в том, чтобы кое-что потестить именно на этой карточке.

Comment: Имея возможность запустить, будет возможность что-то поправить в настройках хотя бы.

Comment: @alexolut Собсна, я запустил, но что делать дальше - ума не приложу.

Comment: попробовать дистрибутивы без гуи?

Comment: Аналогичная проблема, modeset не помогает, так же читал у разработчиков nouveau,что secure boot режет дрова nvidia, обещались поправить(отправили якобы пул реквест в ядро 4.9.11.**)

Comment: у меня память, на котором биос стоит, сгорел из-за нагрева, после того, как я обновил ядро, а там драва для моей видюхи кривые были.  думаю. придется пересобирать тебе ядро или попробовать 16.10